Attempt to get access token and get URL rejected: Bad hostname
I'm trying to send my first post request using Curl to get an access token, the second line contains the content type header which I am entering as:
'-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" '
This then gives me URL rejected: Bad hostname
    C:\Users\user>
    C:\Users\user>curl -X POST "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token" \
   <html><head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
   <title>411 Length Required</title>
   </head>
   <body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
   <h1>Error: Length Required</h1>
   <h2>POST requests require a <code>Content-length</code> header.</h2>
   <h2></h2>
   </body></html>
   curl: (3) URL rejected: Bad hostname
   C:\Users\user>     -H Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded \
   '-H' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file.

Why is this happening and what should be entered instead?

You are not sending a correct curl request C:\Users\user>     -H Content-Type:     '-H' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Write curl command in one line (use " around all params):
curl -X POST "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ...(rest of options)

Or use Windows cmd multiline syntax:
curl -X POST "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token" ^
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ^
...(rest of options)

^ has to be the the last character on the line.
